# Why make doesn't iterate in my sources files?

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-18.04

I made a makefile fo my project but make doesn't iterate through my source files. I can't figure out what I could do to solve this.

I have 2 source files in my directory atm

Makefile:

```
LIBNAME=hazelicious
FLIBNAME=lib$(LIBNAME).so
VERSION=
CC=g++
CXXFLAGS=-W -Wall -O2 -std=c++17 -fPIC -I./vendor/spdlog/include/
LDFLAGS=-shared -Wl,-soname,$(FLIBNAME)
DSRC=src/
DTGT=
DOBJ=$(DTGT)obj/
DOUT=$(DTGT)bin/
EXEC=$(DOUT)$(APPNAME)
SRC= $(wildcard $(DSRC)**/*.cpp)
OBJ= $(subst $(DSRC), $(DOBJ), $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC)))

all: $(FLIBNAME)

install: 
    @sudo cp $(DOUT)$(FLIBNAME) /usr/local/lib/
    @sudo cp $(DSRC)Hazelicious.h /usr/local/include/
    @echo "Library and header files copied!"

$(FLIBNAME): $(OBJ)
    @mkdir -p $(DOUT)
    @$(CC) -o $(DOUT)$@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    mkdir -p $(DOBJ)
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)

checkvar:
    @echo $(SRC)
    @echo $(OBJ)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(DOBJ)
    @rm -rf $(EXEC)

run:
    @./$(EXEC)
```

Output:

```
g++ -o obj/Hazelicious/Log.o -c src/Hazelicious/Log.cpp -W -Wall -O2 -std=c++17 -fPIC -I./vendor/spdlog/include/
g++ -o obj/Hazelicious/Application.o -c src/Hazelicious/Log.cpp -W -Wall -O2 -std=c++17 -fPIC -I./vendor/spdlog/include/
```

As you can see the second line takes the same `Log.cpp` file

My directories structure:

```
/src
  /Hazelicious
    Application.cpp
    Log.cpp
    ...
/obj
  /Hazelicicous
/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting this:

```
SRC= $(wildcard $(DSRC)**/*.cpp)
```

to find all `.cpp` files in all subdirectories of `$(DSRC)`, you'll be disappointed.  The `**` special globbing sequence is non-standard and only supported by some shells (like zsh, or bash if you enable a special option).  It's not part of POSIX standard globbing and is not supported by GNU make's `wildcard` function.  You'll have to use a standard implementation such as:

```
SRC := $(shell find $(DSRC) -name \*.cpp)
```

(use simple variable assignment (`:=`) here, not recursive variable assignment (`=`) for a big efficiency improvement).

Also this:

```
OBJ= $(subst $(DSRC), $(DOBJ), $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SRC)))
```

can get you into trouble because `subst` substitutes *all* instances, even in the middle of words, even if there is more than one instance in a word.  Much better (and simpler) is just:

```
OBJ := $(patsubst $(DSRC)/%.cpp,$(DOBJ)/%.o,$(SRC))
```

The reason you see the same source file is that your recipe is wrong:

```
$(OBJ): $(SRC)
        mkdir -p $(DOBJ)
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Suppose `SRC` resolves to `src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp src/biz.cpp`.  Then `OBJ` resolves to `obj/foo.o obj/bar.o obj/biz.o`.  So, after expanding the target and prerequisite of the above rule, make will get this:

```
obj/foo.o obj/bar.o obj/biz.o : src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp src/biz.cpp
        mkdir -p $(DOBJ)
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

When make sees multiple targets in an explicit rule, it treats that as multiple explicit rules, one for each target, like this:

```
obj/foo.o : src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp src/biz.cpp
        mkdir -p $(DOBJ)
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
obj/bar.o : src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp src/biz.cpp
        mkdir -p $(DOBJ)
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
obj/biz.o : src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp src/biz.cpp
        mkdir -p $(DOBJ)
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

You can see that in all your rules, the first prerequisite (which is what `$<` expands to) will be `src/foo.cpp`, and that's exactly the behavior you observe.

Make doesn't somehow magically loop through all the targets and prerequisites and match them up for you.

In make you always write a rule that builds a single target, from a list of that target's prerequisites.  In your case, you probably want to write a *pattern rule* like this:

```
$(DOBJ)/%.o : $(DSRC)/%.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

instead of the explicit rule above.  This provides make with a pattern it can use to build any target that matches it, and lists a prerequisite of the associated `.cpp` file.

Comment: Super great answer! Thank you, I learned a lot! But it seems that $(DSRC)/%.cpp doesn't return anything.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your comment _it seems that $(DSRC)/%.cpp doesn't return anything_.  What does that mean?

Comment: Founded ;) 

Note that expansion using ‘%’ in pattern rules occurs after any variable or function expansions, which take place when the makefile is read. See How to Use Variables, and Functions for Transforming Text.

Comment: I was trying to echo it

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to say.  If there's a problem please state it more clearly.  If you remove your `$(OBJ): $(SRC) ...` rule and replace it with the above pattern rule, it will work correctly as I've described.