# Making multiple libraries automatically with Make

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a framework where each folder in the source directory becomes a library. I haven't gotten to the .d dependencies yet, I am stuck trying to get the `LLIST` (library list) expansion to work.

My makefile is as follows:

```
# Directories
OBJDIR = obj
TGTDIR = target
INCDIR = include
SRCDIR = src
TSTDIR = tests
LIBDIR = lib
DEPDIR = .d
DIRS = $(OBJDIR) $(TGTDIR) $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR) $(DEPDIR)

# Target name
TGT = caffeine
LLIST = utils middleware

OBJS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/**/*.c))
INCS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.h, $(INCDIR)/%.h, $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/**/*.h))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TGTDIR)/$(TGT)

$(TGTDIR)/$(TGT): $(LIBDIR)/$(LLIST).so
    touch $@

$(LIBDIR)/$(LLIST).so: $(OBJDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.o
    touch $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.c
    touch $@

.PHONY: folders
folders:
    mkdir -p $(DIRS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(DIRS)
```

The error I'm receiving is.
`makefile:35: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax`
Which is this line.
`$(OBJDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.c`

To add for clarity the folder structure is as follows.

```
src
  |-utils
      |-utils.h
      |-utils.c
      |-hash.c
      |-json.c
  |-middleware
      |-middleware.h
      |-middleware.c
      |-req.c
      |-res.c
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, what does that line expand to?

```
OBJDIR = obj
TGTDIR = target
SRCDIR = src
LIBDIR = lib

TGT = caffeine

LLIST = utils middleware

$(TGTDIR)/$(TGT): $(LIBDIR)/$(LLIST).so
        ...

$(LIBDIR)/$(LLIST).so: $(OBJDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.o
        ...

$(OBJDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/$(LLIST)/%.c
        ...
```

expands this way. which is obviously not right:

```
target/caffeine: lib/utils middleware.so
        ...
```

This says that the target `target/caffeine` has two prerequisites: the first is `lib/utils` and the second is `middleware.so`.  I expect that's not what you wanted.

```
lib/utils middleware.so: obj/utils middleware/%.o
        ...
```

This is not actually a pattern rule: a pattern rule **MUST** have a pattern matching character (`%`) in the target.  This creates two targets, `lib/utils` and `middleware.so`, and each one depends on two prerequisites: `obj/utils` and the literal file named `middleware/%.o` (because this is not a pattern rule).

```
obj/utils middleware/%.o: src/utils middleware/%.c
        ...
```

This tries to create an explicit rule for the target `obj/utils` and the pattern rule for the pattern `middleware/%.o` in the same rule, which is illegal and that's why make complains.

In short, you can't just create a variable with multiple words in it, like `LLIST = utils middleware`, then plop that variable down into the middle of things and expect make to somehow do some type of iteration over those words and create multiple rules, or whatever.  That's not how variable expansion works in a makefile: the variable is simply expanded and the results are parsed exactly as if you'd written the makefile without variables at all.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518389/939557 for why using `$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/**/*.c)` can't work.

Comment: is there anything to do here then? I was thinking about using the `include` syntax with a foreach on the LLIST, so it expands correctly to build the .o from /mylib/*. But I'm not sure how I can make the recipes for target with that output. I also wouldn't know how to accomplish this with `include`. But I just want to see if thats possible. @MadScientist

Comment: You will not get very far thinking of a makefile as a procedural language, like a shell script.  A makefile is a declarative language: you state the rules that you want and let make figure out how to do things.  One of make's primary concepts is that one rule builds one target (you can have one recipe build multiple targets but that is more complicated).  So first you should define a rule (probably a pattern rule) that builds ONE target: one .o or one .so.  Then you provide a list of targets to be built.  Make will figure out how and when to use your rules to build those targets.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm thinking that way. I am trying to work the idiosyncrasies out. I'm thinking sub makefiles would work best then. @MadScientist it appears that `$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/**/*.c` is working for me.

Comment: Now I'm thinking sub makefiles would not work when i add .d files for dependency tracking.

Comment: In GNU make, and all traditional shells, `**` is identical to `*` (see the answer I linked to for why).  So, if you have only one level of subdirectory then it will work, just as using `*` will work.  If you have multiple levels of subdirectories then `**` will not do what you expect (it won't match things in those sub-subdirectories).